# Authentication failure while cloning Azure repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm trying to clone a repository using bash script and I face issues while authentication.
I faced this issue while running it manually as well.

So, the idea is to avoid giving username and password manually.

```
git clone https://<username>:<password>@<my_Azure_repo_url> 
fatal: Authentication failed for '<my_Azure_repo_url>'
```

I used personal access token instead and faced the same issue.

```
git clone https://<username>:<PAT>@<my_Azure_repo_url> 
fatal: Authentication failed for '<my_Azure_repo_url>'
```

However, it did work with the following:

```
MY_PAT=yourPAT # replace "yourPAT" with ":PatStringFromWebUI"
B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}" clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

But adding this in our script is a bit expensive. We've to raise it to the vendor and they've to make these changes on their side and send us a new package again and this might be against their best practices or they might deny doing so as this doesn't happen with other TLAs.

Can someone please explain why this wouldn't work with us?

```
git clone https://<username>:<password>@<my_Azure_repo_url>
```

Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When cloning Azure Repo, you could use HTTP PAT or username&password using [Git Credential Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops).

Refer to this official link for details: [Clone Git Repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=git-command-line#clone-any-git-repo)

In Azure DevOps UI, click Generate Git Credentials:

[image]

Copy the password:

[image]

The HTTP username&password method should work well.

[image]

Comment: I used PAT as you suggested and it didn't work. However, I just want to mention that the url starts with https://azuredevops.<domain>.com. It's a private repository. Do you think it might be related to the security policies on the repository or the project.